# Why do I have to Include other entities into my Linq query?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, lazy-loading, aspnetboilerplate, ef-core-2.0

In the below query, why do I have to include the related entities in my query to get a value for them? I mean why Lazy-loading does not seem to work and do I have to do Eager-loading instead?

```
var acceptedHitchRequest = await _acceptedRequestRepository.GetAll()
                                                                    .Include(p => p.HitchRequest)
                                                                    .Include(p => p.CarparkRequest)
                                                                    .Include(p => p.HitchRequest.User)
                                                                    .Include(p => p.CarparkRequest.User)
                                                                    .Where(p => (input.HitchRequestId.HasValue ? p.HitchRequest.Id == input.HitchRequestId : p.CarparkRequest.Id == input.CarparkRequestId)
                                                                                && p.IsActive).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
            if (input.HitchRequestId.HasValue && acceptedHitchRequest.HitchRequest.CreatorUserId == AbpSession.UserId)
```

The `CreatorUserId` in the `if` condition would throw an exception because the `HitchRequest` would be null if I were not using the `Include()`.

Comment: See my comment below. EF Core is a complete rewirte and doesn't have lazy loading yet. A first stage is added with the comming 2.1 version (preview right now) but automatic (without code changes) lazy loading won't be there until next version of EF Core (2.2 or 3.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Inclue()` method provides eager loading instead of lazy loading. I'm explaining to you the difference between the two based on my knowledge.

- **Lazy loading.** It gives you records only for the entity itself and one each time that **related data** (in your case `HitchRequest`) for
  the entity must be retrieved. The `DbContext` class gives you lazy
  loading by default.
- **Eager loading.** When the entity is read, related data is retrieved along with it. This typically results in a single join query that
  retrieves all of the data that's needed. You specify eager loading by
  using the `Include` method.

The first statement without `Include()` is equivalent to the below statement, that's why `HitchRequest` is null if you don't use `Include()`:

```
SELECT * FROM AcceptedRequest;
```

The statement which uses `Include("HitchRequest.User")` is equivalent to the below statement:

```
SELECT * FROM AcceptedRequest JOIN Orders ON AcceptedRequest.Id = HitchRequest.User.AcceptedRequestId;
```

You can refer to [this](http://foreverframe.net/when-use-include-with-entity-framework/) very useful article.

[Entity Framework Loading Related Entities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx), [Eager Loading](http://www.itorian.com/2013/06/what-is-eager-loading-and-what-is-lazy.html) and [Eager Loading in Entity Framework](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/eager-loading-in-entity-framework.aspx)

Comment: Avoid linking to MSDN Articles when its about ASP.NET Core, as most-likely (but wrongly tagged) EF Core is refered which doesn't have lazy loading right now. The EF Core 2.1 Preview 1 adds limited support for lazy loading (you need to inject a delegate yourself and override the properties yourself - until full and automatic support is added in future versions)